# How to update an Excel spreadsheet when I add to another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working with two spreadsheets. On sheet 1, I have a list of the names/customers that I am working with, and on the 2nd sheet I am keeping data for each customer.

My problem is when I add a new name/customer that is not already in the list what formula can I use to automatically add the name/customer to the 2nd sheet?

I was looking everywhere to find these commands and so far I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Use a Table with structured referencing.  The range will automatically adjust as you add (or remove) entries.  If you have O365, you can even SORT or return only UNIQUE entries.

Answer (score 0):

Say `Sheet1` is like:

[image]

In `Sheet2` cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1)
```

and copy far downwards.

`Sheet2` will look just like `Sheet1`.  When you add a name below *Mabel Pines* on `Sheet1`, it will also appear on `Sheet2`.

Comment: Thank you this help, also i have another Question what about if the name is duplicate in Sheet 1 in that case i dont need to add another name formula that i have will automatically count what i need.

Comment: @Marko what version of Excel are you using ?

Comment: Version 2011 ( Build 13426.20308 )

Comment: i also tried to use this command =IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,A2,"") the only problem i have i can't remove empty columns between